# React Native E2E test in Katalon Studio

Tags: react-native, katalon-studio

My team is using Katalon for testing web application. It's comfortable and good tool for that, so when we got to create a mobile app on react-native we were pretty sad when we tried to get it working with Katalon and failed.
We tried to record some actions on mobile, but all views were without names and all actions on them are disabled

[image: Tree state for view]

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @MateMrše, sorry if I wrote it in a confusing way. I'm interested why this happens and if we know a reason - how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Katalon Studio isn't your best option with React-Native, there's no actually a working example or even an article of someone who would recommend Katalon or even made it work with React-Native, you have two options for testing React-Native apps: [Appium](https://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2017/01/06/appium-react-native-quickstart.html) and [Detox](https://hackernoon.com/detox-gray-box-end-to-end-testing-framework-for-mobile-apps-196ccd9564ce)

Both are great options, it's just a matter of personal preferences to choose one of them.